# When will yield actually yield in the function call stack?

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-motor

I am working on tornado and motor in python 3.4.3.

I got three files. Lets name it like `main.py`, `model.py`, `core.py`

I have three functions, one in each...

**main.py**

```
def getLoggedIn(request_handler):
    # request_handler = tornado.web.RequestHandler()
    db = request_handler.settings["db"]
    uid = request_handler.get_secure_cookie("uid")
    result = model.Session.get(db, uid=uid)
    return result.get("_id", None) if result else None
```

**model.py**

```
@classmethod
    def get(cls, db, user_id=None, **kwargs):
        session = core.Session(db)
        return session.get(user_id, **kwargs)
```

**core.py**

```
@gen.coroutine
    def get(self, user_id, **kwargs):
        params = kwargs
        if user_id:
            params.update({"_id": ObjectId(user_id)}) #This does not exist in DB
        future = self.collection.find_one(params)
        print(future) #prints <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x04152A90>
        result = yield future
        print(result) #prints None
        return result
```

The calls look like `getLoggedIn` **=>** `model.get` **=>** `core.get`

core.get is decorated with `@gen.coroutine` and I call `yield self.collection.find_one(params)`
The `print(result)` prints `None` but if I return result and try to print the return value in `getLoggedIn` function it prints .

I believe this is related to asynchronous nature of tornado and the print gets called before yield but I am not sure. It would be a great help if someone could explain about coroutine/generators principles and behavior in different possible cases.

Comment: What does `print(future)` do?

Comment: I erased my previous comment as I see now that's part of your question. What do you expect `result = yield future` to do? I thought that would be a syntax error. That it's not surprises me a little; that it gives `None` surprises me not at all. `yield` is used approximately like `return` but sets up a generator and saves the function state.

Comment: print(future) prints a Future object and print(result) prints None

Comment: I expect result to be a generator object and not future. The `result` returned by `core.get()` is received by `model.get()` as a Future object when I print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every call to a coroutine must be yielded, and the caller must also be a coroutine. So getLoggedIn must be a coroutine that calls:

```
result = yield model.Session.get(db, uid=uid)
```

And so on. See my article on [refactoring Tornado coroutines](http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/) for a detailed example and explanation.

Comment: More than the answer I am happy to see you here ;). I started Motor + Tornado from your video tutorial on your website. Give me sometime before I accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) covers the original specification for generators.
However, `tornado` uses `yield` inside of coroutines in a very specific way: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#how-it-works

Your code doesn't really look or smell like an ordinary generator because the Python notion of generators is being co-opted by `tornado` to define coroutines.
I would say that you don't really want the principles of generator writing, but the principles of *tornado generators* -- a wholly different beast.

Assigning the value of the `yield` is a way for the wrapping `@gen.coroutine` decorator to pass the result of the future back into `core.get`.
That way, `result` is not assigned the future object, but `future.result()`.

`yield future` essentially suspends your function and turns it into a callback that the `future` will invoke, resuming execution at the location of the `yield`.
The asynchronous nature of `tornado` does not allow the `yield` to run before the `print`, as you worried.

Most likely, your Future is not returning anything, or is returning `None` (semantically equivalent, I know).
It might be best to think of `result = yield future` as a specialized version of `result = future.result()`

Comment: The collection doesn't have the document and it shall return `None` and that's fine. What I couldn't understand is the `result` in `getLoggedIn()` gets the object as `Future`. Shouldn't it be `None`

Comment: The only explanation I can think of which is consistent with this is that `model.Session.get` is returning a `Future`. By printing, you've effectively validated that `core.get` returns `None`, not a `Future`.